# Can't make a Fireball execute a command in a radius

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

What I'm trying to do is simply this:

```
/execute @e[type=Fireball] ~ ~ ~ scoreboard players set @a[score_mage_min=1] Cooldown 15
```

And applying it only to players with mage score of 1 in a 2 block radius. So I found out that I had to make something like this:

```
/execute @e[type=Fireball] ~ ~ ~ scoreboard players set @a[score_mage_min=1,r=2] Cooldown 15
```

However it doesn't work, and I cannot realize why.

Comment: Try increasing the radius and see what happens. 2 blocks might be to small to catch the mage in a game tick. Generally, it looks like you should look into detecting the use of the Fireball directly, rather than being near it (which will affect enemy mages).

Comment: I fixed it as you suggested just changing the way it worked the cooldown, but I still can't understand why that command above won't work

Comment: Did you need to use the direction for the fireball. /execute @e[type=Fireball] ~ ~ ~ scoreboard players set @a[score_mage_min=1,r=2,direction:[0.0,0.0,0.0]}] Cooldown 15

Comment: Instead of targeting all players with a mage score of at least 1, why not use `@p` and target the closest player?

Comment: How do you have the fireball casting implemented? There might be a way to select the desired player that way, since this method will, as @MrLemon pointed out, target enemy mages

Comment: Nevermind, I fixed it. But can I remove the fire that the fireball generates? In any way, I don't need it at all in the world.

Comment: @Lionitow It would be useful to know, what the problem was, so people experiencing a similar problem don't have to ask a new question. You can answer your own question btw.

Answer (score 1):

You have to do:

```
/execute @e[type=Fireball] ~ ~ ~ scoreboard players set @a[score_mage_min=1,r=3] Cooldown 15
```

So make it in a radius of 3 instead of 2.
And if you want to make fireballs do:

```
/execute @e[type=Snowball] ~ ~ ~ /summon Fireball ~ ~ ~ {direction:[],ExplosionPower:1}
```